# How to convert svg tag into WebElement

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

```html
<svg stroke-dasharray="" vector-effect="" width="22" height="22" visibility="visible" stroke-width="1" fill="transparent" stroke="transparent"><use xlink:href="#92"></use></svg>
```

How to convert above SVG tag in Web Element with the help of Selenium plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below xpath

```
//*[local-name() = 'svg'][@width='22' and @height = '22']
```

It will select the `svg` element with `width =22` and `height =22` as in your HTML

I tested in chrome console it worked fine

Hope it helps you.

Comment: <div class="aw-commands-commandLiveTextBottomRight">Output Port</div>    for this tag

Comment: Do you mean u have to locate the above div ? for locating the div use the xpath  "//div[@class='aw-commands-commandLiveTextBottomRight']"

Comment: No i want this tag with using OutputPort because this class tag contain 2 more element

Comment: "//div[text()='Output Port']" this xpath will locate the above div tag using its text  ie)Output Port

Comment: Hey suppose 'Ouput Port' is not hardcoded string and if it is stored in some variable e.g. item then what is the solution for it

Comment: String item="Ouput Port";
  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='"+item+"']"));

Comment: without using xpath is there any solution for above code snippet ?